# Highstock - change range input beyond the data max

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highstock on a project and want to allow for dynamically adding more data to the beginning or end of a series by changing the rangeInputs.

The problem is that out of the box, HighStock doesn't seem to validate rangeInput inputs that are beyond the chart's current max/min.

Here's a link to one of their jsfiddles: jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/events-setextremes/

In this example, I would want to type "2011-05-11" into the "To" field and fire an event to go get data.  However, typing "2011-05-11" doesn't ever fire the "setExtremes" event or do anything.

Any ideas?

EDIT
Based on the answer I marked as accepted, I created a Highcharts plugin that overwrites the current functionality.  https://github.com/d-nation/highstock-beyond-extremes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Highstock checks if input date is beyond extremes, and overwrites to min/max value of data. Possible solution is to add two null points and the end and beginning of data, for example:

```
data: [ [timestamp0, null] , [timestamp1, x] .... [timestampN, xN], [timestampN+1, xN] ]
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/MCLXV/

Another solution is to edit sources to prevent that.

Comment: That still limits the extremes to whatever timestamps you wrap the data in.  My requirement is that any date the user wants to enter be validated (so long as the "from" is before the "to").

Comment: So you need to change sources, sorry. Find in Highstock.src.js line with: `// handle changes in the input boxes` and edit lines below.

Comment: Thanks! I made a plugin to do this.  See my edit in the original post

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) You don't need to call `proceed` since you are overwriting that function. 2) I can set date beyond extremes, but still chart is displaying only limited data? You can add info about ordinal axis to prevent that.

Answer (score -1):

Setting `xAxis.ordinal = false` does the trick. See documentation: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

Taken from this answer: [Highstock - Set extremes beyond the data range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711081/highstock-set-extremes-beyond-the-data-range)

Comment: That doesn't answer the OP's question. OP wants to allow the range selector to go beyond the data's min / max, and `xAxis.ordinal = false` doesn't allow that.