# Highstock - Set extremes beyond the data range

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highstock chart with data in the range [t1 , t2] in the x axis, and I want to set the axis extremes to [t1, t3], being t3 higher than t2, resulting this in a portion of the chart with no data. The chart has no navigator nor scrollbar nor range selector.

When I try to do this ...

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(extremes.min, extremes.max + ((30 * 60 * 1000)));
```

... it seems like highstock is replacing the max I provide with the max of the data, but if I log the axis extremes after calling setExtremes, they are the ones I've provided, so it seems like there is an inconsistency between the chart internal options and  what is actually being drawn. I made a fiddle showing this (http://jsfiddle.net/tW9Te/).

Is it possible to do what I'm saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by ordinal axis. Set `xAxis.ordinal = false` and will work the way you want to, see: http://jsfiddle.net/tW9Te/1/